# pyspark with zeppelin on was emr gives NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, emr, apache-zeppelin

I'm running zeppelin on emr to process log some log files using pyspark.

I get this "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3" error.

Not sure how to resolve it. I've looked at various resources. Help appreciated.

--- error log---

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o188.partitions. :
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3    at
>   com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.initialize(EmrFileSystem.java:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2644)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:90)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2678)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2660)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:374)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:228)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:200)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:279)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:207)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
>     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)    at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
>     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)    at
>   org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.partitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:65)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.partitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:47)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor67.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)     ... 32 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the inconvenience! This was due to a change introduced in emr-4.2.0 that accidentally removed the AWS Java SDK libs from the effective Zeppelin classpath. A fix has been pushed to most regions over the past couple of days and will be pushed to all other regions by the end of the week, so this should now work again in emr-4.2.0.